# How to delete information from a map made in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

See that I'm generating a map below and also notice that the map is showing the x and y coordinates. However, I would like to remove this coordinate information, and leave only the map itself. How do I do that, considering the code below?

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- sf::read_sf(temp2)
shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO",]

#Points
Points_properties<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
                                               -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
                                               -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
                                               -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
                                               -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
                                               -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
                                                                                                  -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
                                                                                                  -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
                                                                                                  -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
                                                                                                  -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
                                                                                                  -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651), cluster = c("1", "1", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = shp_subset, aes()) +
  geom_point(data = Points_properties, 
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(Points_properties$Longitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Longitude)+0.1),
           ylim = c(min(Points_properties$Latitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Latitude)+0.1),
           expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Add `scale_x_continuous(labels=NULL)` and corresponding `scale_y_continuous`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is plotted using `ggplot` (as you mention yourself), so you can use all controls available within this package to control the layout of the map.

Here, use `theme_void()` instead of `theme_bw()`:

[image]

Comment: You could do `aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = cluster)`, but you'd need have a cluster name for every lat/long (30 in total) instead of 17. I tested this code by doing `Points_properties$cluster <- c(Points_properties$cluster, rep("3", 13))`

Comment: Thanks for reply. In fact, I thought of using two different colors, for example, red for cluster 1, that is, the points of cluster 1 turn in red, and the points of custer 2 turn in blue.

Comment: You'll achieve that by this code (even if it'll use standard colors), but you'd still need to have a data frame where all variables has the same length (30). At the moment you have 13 points without a cluster name. You need to fix this and you will only need `aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = cluster)`. The other code is just a fix because I don't have your data.